Creating subtype and domain and linking them together in QGIS
I am wondering if there is a similar feature to subtypes in ArcGIS Pro within QGIS software. I want to create a subtype and a domain, and link them together in QGIS, similar to the example below:
Field 1: "landuse_type"
This field should have a dropdown menu with the options: 'Residential' or 'Commercial.'
Field 2: "landuse_subtypes"
This field should have a dropdown menu that depends on the value selected in the "landuse_type" field.
If "landuse_type" is 'Residential,' then the dropdown list for "landuse_subtypes" should include: [Residential A, Residential B, Residential C].
If "landuse_type" is 'Commercial,' then the dropdown list for "landuse_subtypes" should include: [Longitudinal Commercial, Private Commercial, General Commercial].

This is this feature:  https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.2.0/#drill-down-cascading-forms , there is a more detailled explanation : https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-3-2-drive-down-lists-aka-value-relation-widget/
